# Need to Auto generate key in Alphanumeric

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have to generate value with Alphanumeric. Here I've mentioned my function.
* Doubt in this function there is a key called **category_no** I have increment this key by Auto.
**Expected Format:** min value: C0001,C0002,C0003,,,,max value:C9999.

```
   // Inserting New Category
    async function postCategory() {
        for (i = 0; i < categoryJson.length; i++) {
            categoryDefault = {};
            categoryDefault['category_no'] = 
            categoryDefault['category_overview'] = "No overview"
            categoryDefault['category_description'] = "No description"
            categoryDefault['category_created_date'] = new Date()
            categoryDefault['category_modified_date'] = new Date()
            const { error } = await 
           CategoryModel.validateNewCategory(categoryDefault)
            let mongodb = await MongoDB.connect("ecomm_prod_db_category");
            let result = await mongodb.insertOne(categoryDefault);
        };
    };
```

Comment: It's very unclear what you are asking.

Comment: @seesharper I've to generate value for **category_no**. it should be a format like   Expected result: min value: C0001,C0002,C0003,,,,max value:C9999.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a function as following to generate catagory_no,

Use [String.prototype.padStart](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart) to keep the length of string `5` with `0` appended.

For counter use the unnamed self-invoking function passing the count as closure.

```js
let catagory = (() => {
 count = 1;
 return () => {
  if(count < 9999) {
   return `C${(count++).toString().padStart(4, '0')}`
  } throw('Max Limit Reached')
 }
})();

console.log(catagory())
console.log(catagory())
console.log(catagory())
```